# Output a record to PDF file

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to save only the displayed record to a PDF file.

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

If fd.Show Then
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "MAF View for print", "PDF Format (*.pdf)", fd.SelectedItems(1), True
End If
```

This prints to a file, but saves all records instead of only the displayed record.

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.OutputTo` doesn't have a filter option, so you need to filter your form beforehand.

E.g.

```
Dim vBookmark As Variant
' Remember current record to navigate back to it
vBookmark = Me.Bookmark

DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "ID = " & Me!ID
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, ...
DoCmd.ShowAllRecords

Me.Bookmark = vBookmark
```

If you want to hide the filtering from the user, wrap it into `Application.Echo False` / `Application.Echo True`

Comment: this worked great with a few minor changes.  I changed ID to [ID]   and docmd.showallrecords threw an error.  I changed it to me.FilterOn=False